# Приложение только для смартфонов

Tags: android

Необходимо чтобы в Google Play приложение было недоступно для планшетов.
Делаю так:

В манифесте.

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Есть ли более проверенные методы?